# pytorch instance normalization, batch normalization (training) and onnx MVN and openvino MVN

Tags: pytorch, normalization, onnx, batch-normalization, openvino

What is the difference between Instance normalization and MVN and Batch normalization (training mode and batch_size=1) in onnx?

My pytorch model is currently using instance normalization but my ultimate scope is to convert the model in Openvino (version 2020.3) passing through onnx. There is an incompatibility with this normalization (see link below), only batch normalization (BN) is supported.

BN works the same as instance normalization if batch size is 1 and the training mode is on ([here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/75252)). The conversion in onnx works, outputs are the same, but Openvino struggles a lot to deal with this training_mode=on parameter, which is only a dummy features written somewhere in the exported graph.

I see there is a chance to use MVN instead (compatibility operations onnx-openvino [here](https://docs.openvino.ai/2020.3/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Supported_Frameworks_Layers.html#onnx_supported_operators) and [here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_ops_normalization_MVN_1.html) the function, across_channels=false). Onnx seems supporting this operation ([here](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Changelog.md#MeanVarianceNormalization-9)) but I don't know how to use/include it in pytorch, that would be converted in onnx and ultimately supported by openvino. I am not an expert of openvino neither onnx, but this is how life works :).

Is this MVN comparable with instance normalization in pytorch? After retraining a model would I have the same output?

thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

MeanVarianceNormalization (MVN) and BatchNormalization are the supported operators for ONNX in OpenVINO toolkit. Refer to the [ONNX Supported Operators](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/blob/master/docs/MO_DG/prepare_model/Supported_Frameworks_Layers.md#onnx-supported-operators).

Meanwhile, a usual behavior of Model Optimizer is to fuse batch normalization to the convolution layer. Refer to the [Model Cutting](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_Cutting_Model.html#model-cutting) and [Optimization Description](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Model_Optimization_Techniques.html#optimization-description) to learn the method of model preparation.

Comment: Thanks, #Aznie_Intel . Regarding the batch normalization as supported on openvino: there are many issues when you force the training mode on on onnx model. When this parameter is set, openvino cannot convert the model anymore. Please have a look to this [link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/75252)

Comment: Can you share the error that you got when converting the onnx into Intermediate Representation (IR)?

Comment: BatchNorm with training: When using the model optimizer from OpenVINO 2020.3 no error is generated, but the result on the Myriad does not match that of the ONNX. When compiled with the latest release of OpenVINO the error message "Training mode of BatchNormalization is not supported" is displayed.
Instance Normalisation: Compiles OK with OpenVINO 2020.3, but stalls when running on Myriad (not listed as supported here), but runs OK using the latest version of OpenVINO.
OpenVINO 2020.3 must be used as the target Myriad is the Myriad 2

Comment: For 2020.3 OpenVINO release, MeanVarianceNormalization (MVN) has limitation whereby the 
reduction over the batch dimension is not supported, while reduction over all dimensions except batch and channel ones is obligatory. 

Meanwhile, InstanceNormalization is not a supported operator whereas BatchNormalization is a fully supported operator. You may refer to the ONNX* Supported Operators for OpenVINO 2020.3 release. : https://docs.openvino.ai/2020.3/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Supported_Frameworks_Layers.html#onnx_supported_operators